# Method parameter in C#

Tags: c#, methods

I was reading the official C# documentation by Microsoft on the topic of [Method Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/method-parameters) and I came across this paragram.

> A class instance is a reference type, not a value type. When a reference type is passed by value to a method, the method receives a copy of the reference to the class instance. **That is, the called method receives a copy of the address of the instance, and the calling method retains the original address of the instance.** The class instance in the calling method has an address, the parameter in the called method has a copy of the address, and both addresses refer to the same object. Because the parameter contains only a copy of the address, the called method cannot change the address of the class instance in the calling method. However, the called method can use the copy of the address to access the class members that both the original address and the copy of the address reference. If the called method changes a class member, the original class instance in the calling method also changes.

The above-highlighted line confuses me.

My question is?

- What is a called method and calling method in C#?

In line **The class instance in the calling method has an address, the parameter in the called method has a copy of the address, and both addresses refer to the same object.**

Where is the class instance in the calling parameter located in the syntax?

Answer with some example will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: "called method" the method being called. "calling method" the method calling the called method.

Comment: @phuzi How surprising...

Comment: Think about what happens and doesn't happen if your function does this `void Weird(SomeClass c) { c = new SomeClass(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an example makes it clearer:

```
Cake CreateCake(int orderNo){
   var order = new Cake(orderNo);
   Decorate(order );
   return order ;
}
void Decorate(Cake order ){
   ...
}
```

`Decorate` in this case is called by `CreateCake`, so the former is the *called* method, and the later the *calling* method.

The important thing to note is that both of the `order`  variables will point to *the same Cake*. Also note that no cakes will exist until the program is actually run. The source code are just like a recipe for what will happen. 'Class' refers to the type of cake, or to the recipe to create a specific type of cake. 'Instance' or 'object' means an actual physical cake that you can eat.

However, moving actual cakes around the bakery is kind of cumbersome, so we usually put all the cakes in a storage location, and only pass around a piece of paper with the storage location noted down. The `order` variable refers to this piece of paper. You can easily copy the order and give the copy to the decorating department, but both copies will point to the same storage location.

Comment: syntactically where is the class instance located in the calling parameter? Please see the update question!

Comment: @VedicDeveloper you have to separate the source code from what will happen at runtime. The "class instance" only exist at runtime, and will be located on the heap. The `obj` variable will (at runtime) point to this instance, but there can be any number of such variables and objects (at runtime) if the method is called recursively or concurrently.

Comment: isn't the "class instance" mean the object that we declared somewhere in the code and calling it in the method as an argument?

Comment: @VedicDeveloper It might be useful with an analogy. Source code is like a recipe, it contains instructions. But the cake only exist once you actually have baked it. The recipe might say "If the cake require decoration, note the order number and send it over to the decoration department". But it is only once you have baked your cake that you will create a "please decorate order #123" note and send it over. And the point of the quote is that there is only one cake for #123, the person doing the decoration will decorate the existing cake, not bake an entire new cake and decorate *that*.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    // Calling MyMethod:
    MyMethod(someParams);
    ...
}

// This is the called method above:
public void MyMethod(SomeType someParam)
{
   ...
   someParam.SomeProperty = newValue;
   ...
}
```